# How to modify array values in firebase realtime database in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Here I want to modify value of ADDRESS Field. Here the value 1R6RsMMgQ.... represents the uid of each user. Here I am able to reach upto userDetails but I am unable to go to address key for modifying the value. Here the -MXcKsJV... value is the array key value which is generated at the time of pushing the value to database using the push() method.

I tried to update the value by writing this query

```
firebase.database().ref(`/user/${uid}/userDetails/`).update({address: 'change'})
```

By writing this query I would update the userDetails child but this would not been reflected in the array  (i.e. -MXcKs... array)

Can anyone suggest me how to do this?

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of the push key (`-MXcK` level in your database? Are you looking to store multiple addresses per user? If the answer to that is "yes", then which of the user's addresses are your looking to update?

Comment: Yes there will be multiple addresses per user and these address updation depends on users choice.

Comment: In that case: how can we know the user's choice? Do you have the `-M...` key they selected in a variable somewhere?

Comment: No, I haven't store that key in any variable

Comment: So how do you expect the code to determine what node it needs to update? Note that Stack Overflow is a really inefficient interactive chat medium, so I recommend answering in a bit more detail.

Comment: See I have multiple entry like entering email, your height, weight and so on... based on your selection I want to  select that array value. First I thought of updating these values in single array or just by using the set() method but as I wanted to differentiate each an every values so I created array for group of entries.

Comment: That's all fine, but we have no way with the code you shared to know *which* child node (`-M...`) to update.

Comment: So the only option we have is to store these keys in db and at the time of modifying we have to retrieve these keys and update the path ?

Answer (score 1):

Your ref is to /user/1R6.../userDetails/ and not /user/1R6.../userDetails/-MXcK...
You have to update your ref or fix your data structure.